# Get certificate errors when accessing most websites with any browser

Tags: internet-explorer, certificate

**Machines Descriptions:**
Computers with fresh Windows 7 x64 in a domain.

**Problem:**
When I try to access some websites (Google for example) I get certificate error like the website is not trusted.

**What has been tested:**
Changed the date time of the machine but the computer is in a domain and don't allow me to sync with internet time. Reset Internet Explorer default settings, unchecked "check revocation of certificates on the server", turned off firewall, turned off anti-virus and delete internet cache files.

**Observations:**
It's not one computer of the domain but most of them. From the domain controller I can access internet without problems. All updates are installed, but I think this problem appeared after their installation. Although, I checked the updates and event viewer and everything seems okay.

Comment: you might be going out through some kind of proxy that 'mangles' the http request for you when establishing the https session with the target hosts.

Comment: yesterday worked. Today didn't. Didn't configured any proxy in the meantime.

Comment: did not mention anything about **you** configuring a proxy ... keep on keepin on and g'luck.

Comment: ah ok. So what was your meaning then? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the date of your system, if the date is before the certificate expedition date it should not work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't catch it. Could you send some details of the error or screenshots?

Comment: Of course Aitor. I send you this link because it´s exactly this that happens to me when i access Google. https://www.sslshopper.com/assets/images/for_different_site.gif

Answer (score 0):

We solved the problem. Apparently there was an Firewall in the network, that the client didn't know about. That firewall had Antivirus and Antispam scanning checked, and it was checking SMTP, POP3, IMAP, FTP, HTTP and HTTPS. We unchecked that and it worked.